# How to dynamically render partial HTML in Ruby on Rails page?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, dynamic, conways-game-of-life

I'm attempting to build an implementation of Conway's Game of Life in a Ruby on Rails web-app to get adjusted to the framework.

However, I'm running into a bit of a problem.

The way that I want the actual "game" page to work is by creating an html partial that will update the array using the game of life's algorithm, and draw the points to the canvas element.

I've got the code to do this already, and even have the partial built. It looks like this:

```
<% @array = get_next @array %>
    <script>
        function drawArray(){
            //fill rectangles on canvas based on each of @array's values.
        }
        drawArray();
    </script>
```

where the function `get_next` takes in the original array as an argument and creates the next array to be positioned on the canvas accordingly.

When I render this partial on the page originally, it will run the initial array through the algorithm and update the canvas, so I know that the partial works.

My question is, though, how do I get this to happen while the page is open? Basically the goal would be to update the html in some `<div>` on the page with a partial that is generated upon a click request (for now). It would (I think) look a little like this...

```
<script>
    $('#some_div').click(function(){
        //get new partial
        //update old div with new partial code
    });
</script>
```

I'm very new to this, and I realize this may not be even close to the best way to tackle this issue. That said, any criticisms, helpful comments or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I'm open to changing things around if it is considered better practice.

Answer (score 1):

jquery [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) dynamically loads a partial into a div

```
<script>
  $("#some_div").click(function(){
    //get new partial and update display div
    $("#display").load("mypartial-url");
  });
</script>
```

Suggestions:

- keep drawing logic on the client (browser) side i.e. use javascript
- pass the array between the client and the server as json